# Use VBA to Change Y-Axis format for Box-and-whiskers Chart

Tags: excel, vba

I am (successfully) changing Y-axis number formats on a number of charts in Excel using VBA. However, I am having no success with my box-and-whiskers chart. All other charts allow the Y-axis format to change. I've looked for documentation specific to box-and-whiskers and find nothing. Help!

Note: I'm not getting an error... the format just never changes.

```
Private Sub ResetYAxisFormat()

   Dim cht as ChartObject

   set cht = ActiveSheet.ChartObjects("MyBoxAndWhiskersChart")

   'the third one works
   cht.Chart.Axes(xlCategory).TickLabels.NumberFormat = "#,##0.0%"
   cht.Chart.Axes(xlCategory, xlPrimary).TickLabels.NumberFormat = "#,##0.0%"
   cht.Chart.Axes(xlValue).TickLabels.NumberFormat = "#,##0.0%"
   cht.Chart.Axes(xlCategory, xlPrimary).TickLabels.NumberFormat = "#,##0.0%"

End Sub
```

Comment: Wouldn't surprise me if there's a bug since the newer chart formats (e.g. box and whiskers) tend to be not as VBA-friendly. I'm guessing you tried the macro recorder and it wasn't helpful?

Comment: I did not try that - it didn't occur to me. Trying it now...

Comment: @BigBen, that method got me to my answer - thanks. Believe it or not, I've never tried that record-macro approach.

Comment: The newer chart types (box plots, waterfalls, starburst, treemaps) are missing some capabilities, both in the Excel UI and in VBA. I don't know specifically about the box plots since I roll my own with regular charts, but in waterfalls, the axis formatting is missing some pieces in the UI, and if it's missing in the UI it's missing in VBA. And even if it's present in the UI, it still may be missing in VBA.

Answer (score 1):

The following did the trick...

```
cht.Chart.Axes(xlValue).TickLabels.NumberFormat = "#,##0.0%"
```

Comment: It is always great to see someone solve their own question.

Comment: Couldn't/wouldn't have got there without you :-)

Comment: ... though this seems identical to attempt #3 in your question (?)

Comment: @BigBen, regardless, there's a dearth of documentation on automating box-and-whiskers formatting, so I've edited the question to point out that the third option worked, and leaving it here.